# jQuery autocomplete with ui-lightness/ui-darkness theme result list is too wide

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I've got a jQuery autocomplete that uses the ui-lightness theme, but when the result list appears it is much wider than the autocomplete, even if the maximum result text width is less than the autocomplete's width.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"/>
  <script>
   $(function(){
    $("#search").autocomplete({source:"search.php"})
   });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table width="100%" height="100%">
   <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">
     <input id="search" style="width:50%;"/>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Btw this is IE8.

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/WvqBe/1/

Comment: Well, you are styling it with `style="width:50%;"`.

Comment: @j08691 What's wrong with styling it with width:50%?